# Python GTK: How to make it so a checkbox determines if a window will open or not

Tags: python, linux, terminal, gtk

In my program I have one of those annoying popups that alerts the user to go check the settings. I have a checkbox that if checked, is supposed to never show the popup again. I have no idea how to do that. When the check box is checked I need the program to write to a text file called tog_file.txt saying "true". And if the text in tog_file.txt says true, the popup will never display again.
Code:

```
def reminder():
    global tog
    tog = open("tog_file.txt", "r+b")
    tog_r = tog.read()
    if tog_r == "true":
        print "true"
    if tog_r == "":
        global reminder
        reminder = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        reminder.set_position(gtk.WIN_POS_CENTER)
        reminder.set_size_request(450, 205)
        reminder.set_title("Info")

        textbox = gtk.Label("Remember To Go Into The Settings Menu! There are Important Settings that Need to be Reviewed by you!")
        textbox.set_justify(gtk.JUSTIFY_CENTER) 
        textbox.set_line_wrap(True)   

        button = gtk.Button("Close")
        button.connect("clicked", reminder_close)

        toggle = gtk.CheckButton("Don't Show This Message Again")
        item_text = toggle.get_active()
        if item_text == False:
            print "no"
        if item_text == True:
            print "yea"
            tog.write("true")

        fixed = gtk.Fixed()
        fixed.put(button, 300, 160)
        fixed.put(toggle, 50, 165)
        fixed.put(textbox, 50, 50)

        reminder.add(fixed)
        reminder.show_all()

def reminder_close(self):
    reminder.destroy()
```

If you need any additional information, just post a comment.
Thanks StackOverflow :)

Comment: if os.path.exists('file-path'):with open('file-path','r') as f:if f.read() == 'true': skip popup else: show popup

Comment: @cox could you post a reply instead of a comment so I can say that you answered the question, and so I can understand your answer please

Comment: @cox that is not even close to what I'm looking for. I need to be able to tell when to write "true" in the file with toggle.get_active()

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the get_active() method. Check if button.get_active() => boolean and act accordingly. You may also connect the radio bt to 'toggle' signal and in on_toggle function set a class variable with the state of bt: `if bt.get_active():self.ischeck=True
else:self.ischeck = False` or shor way:`self.ischeck = True if bt.get_active() else False`